# How to create a button with a fontawesome string as "icon" and normal text as label in Android?

Tags: android, string, button, label, font-awesome

I'm trying to create a button with a fontawesome string as "icon" and normal text as label in Android

Currently i'm using this ( in **dashboard.xml** ):

```
<Button
       android:id="@+id/ndc"
       style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
       android:layout_width="0dip"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       android:text="@string/icon_ndc"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
       android:shadowColor="#000000"
       android:shadowDx="1"
       android:shadowDy="1"
       android:shadowRadius="1"
/>
```

and this ( in strings.xml , it's a fontawesome icon)

```
<string name="icon_ndc">&#xf19c;</string>
```

How can i add a label that must have different size , color etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SpannableString` as text to the button. With that you can set different font based on start-end index within the string. [Refer](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html)

You can alternatively use [Iconify](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify) library for easy usages of font awesome across other widgets and with animation!!